# Check when resources are available from AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm using `AVFoundation` and creating `AVPlayer`'s but getting some errors as shown below.

These are the 2 errors:

> 2017-01-06 15:51:19.974693 DemoApp[11855:3855225] Video player Status
>   Failed: player item error = Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
>   Code=-11839 "Cannot Decode" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174253ef0
>   {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12913 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The decoder required for this media is busy.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions that decode media
>   and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode}
>
> 2017-01-06 15:51:19.974783 DemoApp[11855:3855225] Video player Status
>   Failed: player error = (null)

I'm able to print these 2 errors like so:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    ///.. other code ..///

      case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed: {
        print("Video player Status Failed: player item error = \(self.player.currentItem.error)")
        print("Video player Status Failed: player error = \(self.player.error)")
    } 
}
```

Apple's documentation for this error:

- An enum value: `case decoderTemporarilyUnavailable = -11839`
- Link to this error: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/averror.code/1388106-decodertemporarilyunavailable

It seems Apple has a limit to how many `AVPlayer`'s the entire system could create; which means all apps share these resources. I want to check for this so that I could respond appropriately in my app.

**Is there a way to check when these resources are available? Like when is the decoder available?**

### Update 1

Below is snippet of what I'm doing. On an iPhone 6s, there seems to be a limit of 16 `AVPlayer`'s that can be created and played simultaneously. In this app, the function below called `refreshVideoPlayersAndTable` creates 10 `AVPlayer`'s every time the app launches and starts playing all of them. When the app goes to background, I release these shared resources by deleting and removing all video players.

Note: This error occurs mostly if I use another app that plays many videos simultaneously and is therefore using the shared resources from iOS. There aren't too many apps that use 10 or more `AVPlayer`'s at once but there are a couple. When I use another app that does so and then switch to my app right away, then I need to put the `delay` like below to avoid any decode error's.

**My main goal is to check for when the resources are available instead of using an arbitrary `delay` in order to create the video players.**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        registerNotifications()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: Notification) {

        /// Hack: Without a delay, it seems that iOS does not have the resources
        /// available to refresh the AVPlayer's. We get `decode errors` if we
        /// instantiate them without a delay.
        delay(1) { [weak self] in
          self?.refreshVideoPlayersAndTable()
        }
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: Notification) {
      /// Release shared resources - delete and remove all AVPlayer's
        removeAllVideoPlayers()
    }

    func registerNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidEnterBackground), name: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationWillEnterForeground), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information on what you are trying to achieve? Are you creating multiple avplayer? When does this fail?

Comment: I need to see the code you wrote to use the avplayer.

Comment: @manishg I updated my question, please see **Update 1**

Comment: @OrenEdrich I updated my question, please see **Update 1**

Comment: Thanks for updating this- you helped me solve my own issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should limit `AVPlayer` instances associated with `AVPlayerItem`s simultaneously. Just replace player's current item with `nil` for players not visible on the screen:

```
player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
```

Looks like there is no other way to check if resources available else than to try to play and get this error.

Comment: Thanks for response! Is there any documentation that states we cannot check for resources? I'm trying to learn how you determined this - thanks

Comment: I updated my question, please see **Update 1** - let me know if this is correct approach